# How to solve this error? APP debugging

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

[image]

I don't know what this error means:

> Assert failed: Unsupported format for depth and stencil buffers...

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem today when I was porting form cocos2d-x v3.4 to v3.14. There was some difference in appDelegate.

try this 
in `AppDelegate.h` declare this method.

```
virtual void initGLContextAttrs();
```

in `AppDelegate.cpp`

```
void AppDelegate::initGLContextAttrs()
{
    // set OpenGL context attributes: red,green,blue,alpha,depth,stencil
    GLContextAttrs glContextAttrs = {8, 8, 8, 8, 24, 8};

    GLView::setGLContextAttrs(glContextAttrs);
}

// if you want to use the package manager to install more packages,
// don't modify or remove this function
static int register_all_packages()
{
    return 0; //flag for packages manager
}
```

see if this resolves the issue. It did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

It shows the issue is with the eaglview you are creating,can you please paste the appcontroller and appdelegate content here as the error comes by running the content in applicationdidfinishlaunching function placed in appcontroller.

and which Cocos2dx version you are using?